# Concave, convex function

Tags: calculus, functions

When drawing the function

$f(x)=arccos(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2})$

on the computer, one sees that $f$ is clearly concave on the interval $x \in (-\infty,0] \cup [0,\infty)$. However, the function $f$ has the second derivative

$f^{''}(x)=-\frac{4x}{(1+x^2)^2}$

which says that $f$ is convex $\forall x < 0$ and concave $\forall x > 0$. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your computation you are writing $\sqrt {x^{2}}=x$ which is wrong. Actually, $\sqrt {x^{2}}=|x|$. You  should get $f^{''}(x)=-\frac{4|x|}{(1+x^2)^2}$.